# If a limit is equal to another, does it mean they exist?

Tags: calculus, limits

I am working on problem 10 of Spivak's Calculus Chapter 5 Limits.

In 10(c), we proved that $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0}f(x^3)$. I think it is the same for $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0}f(x^2)$.

In 10(d), we gave an example where $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x^2)$ exists, but $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$ does not.

Does it suggest that the equal sign has no assumption on whether both limits on the right and left exist?

Comment: If something does not exist, it cannot be equal to anything...

Comment: Why do you think $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0}f(x^2)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you're working on functions of a real variable, $\lim_{x\to0}{f(x^2)}$ is not necessarily the same as $\lim_{x\to0}{f(x)}$, because for any real $x$, $x^2$ is nonnegative. As such, $\lim_{x\to0}{f(x^2)}=\lim_{x\to0^+}{f(x)}$.

The equality of two convergent limits does imply that they both exist, it's just that the limit as $x^2$ goes to zero is only equal to the limit from the right as $x$ goes to zero, not the both-directional limit.

Thus in cases where $\lim_{x\to0^+}{f(x)}$ is defined but $\lim_{x\to0^-}{f(x)} \not = \lim_{x\to0^+}{f(x)}$, the limit $\lim_{x\to0}{f(x)}$ fails to exist, but $\lim_{x\to0}{f(x^2)}=\lim_{x\to0^+}{f(x)}$.

This can be extended to arbitrary positive integer powers. $\lim_{x\to0}{f(x^n)}=\lim_{x\to0^+}{f(x)}$ for even $n$, and $\lim_{x\to0}{f(x^n)}=\lim_{x\to0}{f(x)}$ for odd $n$.

Comment: +1. For example if $f(x)=0$ for $x\ge 0$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x<0$ then $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x^2)=0$ but $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$ does not exist.