# Why the proof logic in Spivak's Calculus work for $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0}f(x^3)$ but not $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0}f(x^2)$?

Tags: calculus, limits

This is related to the question I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4564734/if-a-limit-is-equal-to-another-does-it-mean-they-exist?noredirect=1#comment9604264_4564734). I am not clear about the proof given in the answer book in Chapter 5 Question 10(c) of Spivak's Calculus.

**Question:**

proved that $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0}f(x^3)$.

**Answer:**

[image]

PS: Looks like there are some typos: In the first line: ...if $x^3$ is close to $0$. On the fourth line: ...Thus, $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0} f(x^3) = l$. Am I right?

My question is why the same proof logic cannot be applied to $f(x^2)$. In which part of the proof, does  $f(x^2)$ not work?

And also, why do we need to first assume $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)$ and prove $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}f(x^3)$, then we need to do it in another direction. Does the equal sign mean if and only if?

Comment: If $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ then $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) $ does not exist, but $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x^2)$ exists.

Comment: Essentially yes for your last question. With limits you always need to suppose or prove they exist before talking about them.

Comment: Also, uh, that doesn't work @Henry, you might be confused with the derivative not existing at $0$?

Comment: The following is the proper version $$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x^2)=\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)$$ The function $x\mapsto f(x^2)$ does not provide any information about the behaviour of $f(x)$ for negative values of $x,$ unlike $f(x^3).$ But the equality $$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x^2)=\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$$ holds provided the limit on RHS exists.

Comment: As for the typos, you are right about the 4th line but the 1st one is correct (and means what you wrote).

Comment: @Henry If you define a limit to be where the left- and right-handed limits are equal, then yes $\lim_{x\to 0} \sqrt{x}$ would not exist because $\sqrt{x}$ does not take in negative numbers in its domain, but the limit can be defined at any limit point of the domain of $\sqrt{x}$.  Since the domain of $\sqrt{x}$ is $[0,\infty)$, and $0$ is a limit point for this interval, then by said definition, $\lim_{x\to 0}\sqrt{x}$ is defined and equals $0$.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc For the proof provided above, can I just replace $x^3$ with $x^2$? The proof looks OK to me. But I am not sure which part is wrong.

Comment: For $x^3$ there is no problem. The existences of the limits of $f(x)$ and $f(x^3)$ at $0$ are equivalent. But for $f(x)$ and $f(x^2)$ they are not equivalent.